# localStorage: Second value doesn't get stored?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

This is probably a simple syntax error or similar, but I can't for the life of me see it. I've used localStorage without problems before on much more complex structures, so I'm baffled why this doesn't work.

```
$('.symbols').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked"){
        setPreferences("symbols", true);
    } else {
        setPreferences("symbols", false);
    }
});

$('.length').on('change', function() {
    setPreferences("length", $(this).attr('value'));
});

function setPreferences (key, value) {
    console.log("Key[ " + key + " ], Val[ " + value + "]");
    localStorage[key] = value; // I've also tried "" + value
}
```

Setting *symbols* works just fine, but *length* is not stored. The console.log prints the intended key / value pair on the corresponding event, and I can see from the Chrome debugger that it tries to alocate space - it just isn't there when inspecting. The order on fired events does not matter, only "symbols" is stored correctly.

Console print when selecting the value 16 from the select, "length":

> Key[length], Val[16]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are using 'length' as key name. But as length is already a property of localstorage object, you cannot use it as a custom keyword.
Try with that and see if its working:

```
setPreferences("customlength", $(this).val());// as suggested on other answer, better to use .val()
```

Comment: Ahh, I should have thought about that. Thanks, that did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right syntax

```
$('.length').on('change', function() {
    setPreferences("length", $(this).val());
});
```

`val()` permits to retrieve value of input element : http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However, as I'm saying the console.log prints the correct key and value - so the problem isn't that the function is passed a null value.

Comment: Have you tried to use another word than "length" for the key? It could be a special keyword.

Comment: @roasted Beat you to it, the problem was indeed the reserved keyword "length". Thank you again for your reply.